# How can i display a 4 diferent themplate for the archive page

Tags: theme-development, page-template

How can i display 4 diferent themes for an archive page 
When i click on the right in corner i want to display another theme, another Css style (my own)

Something like this.

```
http://tvpedia.org/lista-seriale/seriale-noi-2012
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the site you linked to is just using a url parameter to specify which view to serve.  A simply way to accomplish this is to create four different loop templates, each employing a different layout.  Using the example site, you would need the following:

```
loop-complex.php, loop-simple.php, loop-poster.php and loop-logo.php
```

Then your normal templates (index.php, archive.php) would start out as something simple like this:

```
<?php 
get_header();

$view = 'complex';
get_template_part( 'loop', $view );

get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Now all that is needed is to process the url parameter and change which loop template is pulled in based on it's value (and of course making sure it is a valid value):

```
$view = 'complex';
$mode = stripslashes( $_GET["layout"] );
$modes = array('complex', 'simple', 'poster', 'logo');
if(in_array($mode, $modes)) $view = $mode;
get_template_part('loop', $view);
```

Then you just code the four different loops to make the different layouts appear how you want them to.